# representation of the extended ascii characters

Tags: erlang

The ascii code of the character é is decimal 130 or hex 82

$é. return the value 233 ! why ?

More generally, does this fonction exist ?
f(13) return $\r
f(130 return é or $é

Comment: ASCII only goes up to 127, there is no single "extended ASCII" encoding - which one are you referring to?

Comment: I can't tell you for sure but there are many ways to encode text. Sounds like the use something different than the normal table.

Comment: @David Take a Table ascii: you find a first part (0 to 127) and an extended part (128 to 255)

Comment: also, if you accept some of the answers for your earlier questions, that people spent valuable time providing, you may gain more respect and sympathy here on SO. Just find the best answer, and click the big tick near the top left of the answer.

Comment: @Bertaud No, there are a multitude of different 8 bit "extended ASCII" encodings. Which one are you using?

Comment: the erlang one of course

Comment: @Bertaud What is the name of that encoding? Is it ISO-8859-1 (Latin-1)?

Comment: @David: have I forget to click in one of my previous questions ?

Comment: iso-8859-1: I suppose yes (french characters)

Comment: May I correct my faults by scaning all my questions ?

Comment: @Bertaud yes indeed you can; don't forget this one too!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ISO-8859-1 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) for the character é is indeed 233. Mystery solved.

Comment: Ok, my question was bad. Now I click the tick !

Comment: @Bertaud I can't explain the 0%, perhaps SO will take a little time to catch up

Comment: I scanned my questions, selected the best answers and always 0% :-(

Answer (score 2):

$X is just syntactic sugar for the code of the character X. Originally, erlang used latin-1 encoding, but after R13A it started to implement unicode support. Modern releases, now define $X as syntactic sugar for the unicode codepoint of X. For your case $é codepoint is the same as latin-1 code since unicode was designed as a superset of latin-1.

http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/stdlib/unicode_usage.html#id60745

Be careful when you think about unicode. Unicode codepoints are just numbers, and they can be greater than 255. That means they need some kind of encoding to be passed to binaries (e.g. utf-8).

As for your second question, you don't need that function, $\r **is** 13, just test it in your shell.

Comment: AFAIR, the unicode codepoints were defined explicitly such that ASCII and Latin1 are subsets, i.e. that the ASCII values and Latin1 values are the same as the unicode codepoints for the same character. That "turns out" you mention has been explicitly designed into unicode.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I didn't mean to say that it was by chance. Anyway, it's a good point, I'll clarify my comment